# Akka HTTP: the requested resource could not be found

Tags: java, akka-http

I'm using the [Akka HTTP "Minimal Example"](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/index.html#minimal-example) for my first steps in Akka HTTP.

```
private Route createRoute() {
  return route(
    path("hello", () ->
      get(() ->
        complete("<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))));
}
```

Now I want to add a route to my `resources/web/test.html`, similar to an example on the ["Directives"](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/index.html#basics) page:

```
private Route createRoute() {
  return route(
    pathSingleSlash(() ->
      getFromResource("web/test.html")
    ),
    path("hello", () ->
      complete("<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>")));
}
```

But `http://localhost:8080` is showing me the following:

```
The requested resource could not be found.
```